# Pass parameters to data-sly-include in sightly/HTL

Tags: aem, sightly, htl

I have a piece of Sightly/HTL code as follows -

```
<div class="tooltip_modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h5>Tooltip</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>${properties.tooltip_textfield}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note that `${properties.tooltip_textfield}` is hard coded into the code.
I am including this code in my component like this -

```
<div data-sly-include="/custom/tooltip-modal/tooltip-modal.html" data-sly-unwrap></div>
```

Now I want to pass a parameter to data-sly-include statement so that when my HTML code is rendered, the passed parameter should be placed in place of `${properties.tooltip_textfield}` .

In other words -

Calling this

```
<div data-sly-include="/custom/tooltip-modal/tooltip-modal.html" parameter= "Dummy Text" data-sly-unwrap></div>
```

Should render this -

```
<div class="tooltip_modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <h5>Tooltip</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Dummy Text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Is this possible?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45325568/aem-sightly-how-to-reuse-variables/45326997#45326997

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe what you're after is the [Sightly Template and Call](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/htl/docs/block-statements.html#template%20&%20call) feature.

templates/tooltip.html:

```
<template data-sly-template.tooltip="${@ text}" class="tooltip_modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h5>Tooltip</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>${text}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

component.html:

```
<sly data-sly-use.tooltipTmpl="templates/tooltip.html"
data-sly-call="${tooltipTmpl.tooltip @ text='Sample text'}" data-sly-unwrap>
</sly>
```

Comment: Hi, I am having difficulties with achieving this. I have 2 html, and I want to include html1 into html2, so in my html2 I've included it something like `<sly data-sly-use.comp="/apps/base/components/content/html1.html" data-sly-call="${comp.card1 @ type='compcards'}" data-sly-unwrap>
     </sly>` But when I run, I get **Identifier /apps/base/components/content/html1.html cannot be correctly instantiated by the Use API**. Could you please suggest if am missing anything?